# wordpress login stays in the same page even after accepting password

Tags: php, wordpress

I have deployed a Wordpress website. Primarily it worked fine. But recently I couldn't be able to login to my `dashboard` as it redirects to the login page again even after accepting the password. I have tried following isolated things but neither worked so far!

1. Checked `siteurl` value from options table in the DB. It is fine.
2. Added the following lines in the `wp-config.php` file.

   define('WP_HOME','http://mysiteurl.com');

   define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysiteurl.com');

The front-end works absolutely fine. When press "Log In" button it simply redirects to the following link;
http://mysiteurl.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysiteurl.se%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I am in great trouble! If anybody could help please!

Comment: 1. Make a full backup of the site; 2. Try to replicate the issue in local dev environment; 3. Remove all plugins (just move them out of the `wp-content/plugins` directory) and try to login again. 4. Enable debugging mode in `wp-config.php` file by setting `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);`5. Post back the results here :)

Comment: Turned DEBUG mode ON and getting the following result:
"WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away]
SELECT * FROM qs_users WHERE user_login = 'admin'"

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL server has gone away` means the MySQL does not have enough resources to execute necessary queries for logging in.

If you are on a shared host, try contacting them in order to raise the `max_allowed_packet` value to something like `32M` or `64M`. If you are on a VPS/dedicated server, you can do that yourself in `my.ini` configuration file for MySQL.

You can read more on this [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html) - just look for the `max_allowed_packet` setting.

Comment: My site is on a shared host. I will contact them about what you said. Anyway, thanks for your help!@Topsitemakers